# GitHub Actions - Upload Artifact Failed: Unable to get local issuer certificate

Tags: github, github-actions, github-for-windows

We are using self-hosted runners (Windows) for GitHub actions. Recently, our company changed the proxy. We have updated the System Environment Variables to the new proxy, and we have updated the proxy details in .env file as suggested by [GitHub](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/hosting-your-own-runners/using-a-proxy-server-with-self-hosted-runners) documentation. And we have added the Root CA in the Windows Certificate Manager (Certificates - Local Computer -> Trusted Root Certification Authorities -> Certificates). But when [uploading the artifact](https://github.com/actions/upload-artifact) during workflow run, we got the below error message and workflow is failing.

> Create Artifact Container - Attempt 1 of 5 failed with error: unable to get local issuer certificate
>
> Error: Create Artifact Container failed: unable to get local issuer certificate
> ##[debug]Node Action run completed with exit code 1

How can we resolve this error? Is there anything that should be changed in runner configuration?

Answer (score 0):

This issue is resolved by adding a runner environment variable `NODE_EXTRA_CA_CERTS=<path to certificate` in `.env` file in runner installation folder.